# Quasi-coherent sheaf which is a vector bundle on curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves, quasicoherent-sheaves

This question is inspired by [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384569/projective-modules-restricted-to-smooth-curves) question. Given a quasi-coherent sheaf on a smooth variety $X$ such that its restrictions to curves are finite dimensional vector bundles. Does it follow that the sheaf is necessarily a finite dimensional vector bundle?

Comment: If dimension of $X$ is at least two, then the (constant) sheaf of rational function is quasi-coherent whose restriction to every curve is zero .

Comment: @Mohan: the sheaf of rationals functions of the plane restricted to the $X$-axis is definitely not zero. I may be misunderstanding you. Care to elaborate? I feel like the "(constant)" part of your argument is important.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Assume for simplicity that $X$ is affine and $D \subset X$ is a principal divisor with equation $F$. Then restricting to $D$ means tensoring with $\mathcal{O}_X/F$. Using the resolution $0 \to \mathcal{O}_X \stackrel{F}\to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X/F \to 0$ and invertibility of $F$ in $K(X)$, it is easy to see that the restriction of $K(X)$ is zero.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where $\mathscr E$ is coherent, you can re-use the arguments in the answer to the question you cited. First of all, there is an equivalence of categories between the category of vector bundles over $X$ (i.e. algebraic varieties $E$ with a projection $E \to X$ which locally on $X$ looks like the projection $X \times \mathbb A^n \to X$) and the category of locally free sheaves over $X$, the equivalence being given by sending a vector bundle to its sheaf of sections, and in the other direction, using the relative spec of the symmetric algebra of your locally free sheaf to build an (algebraic) vector bundle out of it. This equivalence respects all sorts of things (tensor products, hom-sheaves, pullbacks, etc.) so you can re-formulate the question as:

> Given a quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathscr E$ such that its restriction to curves are locally free of finite constant rank, is $\mathscr E$ locally free of finite constant rank?

If you assume $X$ integral and smooth, then all you have to show is that $\mathscr E$ is such that the function $x \mapsto \dim \mathscr E_x/\mathfrak m_x \mathscr E_x$ is constant on the set of closed points of $X$.

If you pass a smooth connected curve between any two closed points $x,y \in X$, as in the argument in the answer of the question you quoted, $\mathscr E|_C$ is locally free of constant rank (because smoothness implies the curve is irreducible), so since any two points can be joined by such a curve, $x \mapsto \dim \mathscr E_x/\mathfrak m_x \mathscr E_x$ is constant.

I am trying to think of a counter-example in the case where $\mathscr E$ is quasi-coherent but not coherent.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I am a bit rusty, so I may have overviewed important details, feel free to ping me in the comments if I did.

Comment: The only issue I see with the original argument is that it uses [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FWG) lemma which relies on the Nakayama lemma and it relies on finite generation. But intuitively it seems it should also work without finite generation assumption.

Comment: @user127776 : I had a feeling coherence would kick in somewhere, but I couldn't find anything about this in my notes. Yes, I'm pretty sure there is a counter-example in the quasi-coherent-but-not-coherent case. The coherence is that what allows you to claim that $\mathscr E$ is locally free by knowing that $\dim \mathscr E_x / \mathfrak m \mathscr E_x$ is constant on closed points.